# Fermentation velocity of Brettanomyces Graphs

Tags: fermentation, brettanomyces

I have spent a fair amount of time recently looking into Brett, Brett Sacc and Mixed fermentation; for my next project, but one thing I have really struggled to find is any graphs of different Brett strains or mixed fermentation.

All I have found so far is this page from [Port66](http://www.port66.co.uk/brewing-brettanomyces/) which looks at the fermentation velocity of 100% pure Brett fermentation.

Does anyone else have any sources for other Brett/Sacc fermentation or mixed ( Brett/Sacc/LAB or Brett/Sacc/LAB/Pedio)?

If there are none I will have to do the brews and graph them up and share; I may well do this anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with
 http://www.milkthefunk.com
 These guys have done it all. They have a great wiki on mixed fermentation.

I think the type of graph your asking for really has too many variables to quantify in a simple graph and no one has been up to the challenge. Just to hit the major points would have to factor. OGs, Brett%, Sacc%, Lacto%, Pedio%, etc. Honestly I don't think all the possible interactions with each other have been discovered. Such as at what point will Brett consume Sacc.

Comment: The milkthefunk website has a lot of useful information but some of this was lacking. I may have to do these experiments my self.